# can every model be defined as nn.Sequential?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm learning to use PyTorch. If anyone is familiar with PyTorch could they tell me if all models can be nn.Sequential?

I'm asking because some framework features only accept as input a model defined as nn.Sequential

Comment: I'm using torchgpipe (GPipe implementations) for some testing with pipeline parallelism, and torchgpipe automatically takes the model and makes the partitions the paper describes, as long as the model is nn.sequential
My question is if I can transform any model into nn.sequential to use this library

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only in the sense that you could wrap a highly complex model as a single step in ‘nn.Sequential’. If you want an example of a model that breaks sequential behavior, look up ResNet and its ilk. These require data to be passed between “layers”; however, even those can be implemented using ‘nn.Sequential’ by creating special ‘nn.Module’ classes to handle the residual functionality, and stacking those blocks together into sequential.